# Reposition scroll bar of ListView with padding

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a `ListView` with padding to the right (and left).

Currently the list looks something like this:

```
-----------------  |
| ROW         | |  |
|-------------| |  |
| ROW         | |  |
|-------------|#|  |
| ROW         |#|  |
|-------------| |  |
| ROW         | |  |
-----------------  |
```

Where the right-most line is the edge of the screen, with the `#`s being the scrollbar and the white space to the right of it being the `ListView`'s padding to the right.

What I is for the scroll bar to be to the right of the padding like this:

```
                    _
-----------------  | |
| ROW           |  | |
|---------------|  | |
| ROW           |  |#|
|---------------|  |#|
| ROW           |  |#|
|---------------|  | |
| ROW           |  | |  
-----------------  |_|
```

Is it possible to move the scrollbar like that or will I have to change the layouts for each row to have an invisible border of the right size?

Note currently each row has a separate background set by the adapter, since I'm making a floating window for my `ListView` and unfortunately one of my screens require me to do this in order to get it to look the way I want.

Comment: to clarify for future readers: `outsideOverlay` does not change the horizontal position of the items in the list; `outsideInset` adds some padding, moving the right-hand edge of the items in a bit.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<ListView
    ...
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

Comment: If I use this my scrollbar is not shown anymore. It just disappears

Comment: I used android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset", it is working fine on HTC Desire but not on Galaxy S. Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: +1. And if it did not work with you, make sure you are NOT using any `margin attributes` in the ListView.

Comment: work fine with padding, instead of margin in TextView.

Answer (score 37):

add this to your list view

```xml
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
```

it will add a little padding and the scroll bar will be outside

Comment: I want to have padding on right side. This solution not working for me