# RecyclerView's scrollbar not appearing on edge of screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, androidx

I'm trying to add a margin around my `RecyclerView` whilst enusring it can scroll vertically but for some reason the scrollbar does not position itself at the end/right of the screen. Is this an issue specific to Android X?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an issue specific to Android X?

Not really.

The issue here is you are specifying padding on the container of the RecyclerView.

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

This is because the rect used to draw the scrolls bars are limited to the rect where is drawn the RecyclerView. This is also the reason because the scroll bars restraint on the top.

Remove these and you are going to obtain the scroll bars positioned on the border of the screen.

Check also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

Comment: Still need padding around the `RecyclerView` without moving the scrollbar

Comment: In that case, the padding should be added into the adapter items

Comment: Or,  not sure if it works but you can try `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23421022/1797950

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

The bar is in the recyclerview, the recycler is constrained by the padding.

Quick fix:

Add padding to the recylerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingEnd.../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Good practice:
List should be full width so user interactions are not hindered by unknown spacings. Add the padding to the item you are inflating in the adapter.